# How to group by two columns, calculate weighted mean, return DataFrame, in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Goal: Take a DataFrame, group by two columns of that DataFrame, calculate the weighted mean of a third column, and return a DataFrame. What adjustments are needed in Reprex below?

```
##  REPREX
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Turn into DataFrame
md = {"group1": ["A", "A", "B", "B", "A"],
      "group2": [1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
      "var1":[343, 345, 567, 345, 212],
      "wt":[1.2, 1.3, 1.8, .9, 1.9]}

# Turn into DataFrame
my_df = pd.DataFrame(md)

# This works to get unweighted means:
grouped__means = my_df.groupby(["group1", "group2"], as_index=False)[["var1"]].mean()

# This does NOT work for weighted means:
grouped__wtd_means = my_df.groupby(["group1", "group2"], as_index=False)[["var1"]].agg(np.average(weights=my_df["wt"]))

# What needs to change?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `GroupBy.apply` here.

```
df.groupby(['group1', 'group2']).apply(lambda x: np.average(x['var1'], weights=x['wt']))

group1  group2
A       0         345.000000
        1         262.709677
B       1         493.000000
dtype: float64
```

Comment: How can I return a DataFrame with three columns group1, group2, var1, rather than a Series (as this example does)? I realize can get a DataFrame by adding .reset_index() at the end of the line line of code but then it assigns 0 as the new column name (I'd like it to be "avg")

Comment: `.reset_index(name='avg')` would do @tall_table

Answer (score 1):

With many groups calculate the weighted average yourself to avoid the apply. Multiply the values by the weights and sum, then divide by the sum of the weights. `pandas` will align on the Index for the division.

```
(df['var1'].mul(df['wt']).groupby([df['group1'], df['group2']]).sum()
     .divide(df.groupby(['group1', 'group2'])['wt'].sum()))

group1  group2
A       0         345.000000
        1         262.709677
B       1         493.000000
dtype: float64
```